# problem while creating android project with command line

Tags: android, command-line, compilation, target

```
android create project \
    --package com.example.helloandroid \
    --activity HelloAndroid \ 
    --target 2 \
    --path <path-to-your-project>/HelloAndroid
```

Hi

I came across this in the developers site for android.Can you plz tell me what does target 2 mean in the above commands.

I want to specify different targets but not able to find the codes mapped with tagets

Thnx in adv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's API level (1.5, 2.1, 2.3...)
Do android list targets to see the IDs, they depend on what API SDKs you have installed, they're not global identifiers.
Edit: I think you can also use android-2, android-5... which *are* global.